# How to find frequent itemsets using apriori in R?

Tags: r, apriori

I have a text file: `MyData.txt` with this `itemsets`:

```
     items                              
[1]  {542931}                           
[2]  {542380}                           
[3]  {81387,542448,360015,542613,542931}
[4]  {546845,542614}                    
[5]  {1123614}                          
[6]  {542931}                          
[7]  {1014660}                          
[8]  {1088953}                          
[9]  {1138035}
```

I want to find `frequent itemsets`. Here is my code:

```
tr <- read.transactions("MyData.txt",format = "basket", cols = NULL)
freq_is <- apriori(tr, parameter = list(target = "frequent itemsets", support = 0.00001))
```

but when I inspect the `freq_is`, count of `{542931}` is two, which is incorrect (there are three `itemsets` have 542931). In fact, `Apriori` just counts `items [1]` and `items [6]` and it ignores `items [3]`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please use `dput()` for you data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you use `','` as a separator in `MyData.txt`, but you do not specify it in `read.transactions()`, which splits at whitespaces per default.

So if you change your code to:

```
tr <- read.transactions("MyData.txt",
                        format = "basket",
                        sep = ",", 
                        cols = NULL)
```

You will see that the count of 542931 is actually 3:

```
summary(tr)
transactions as itemMatrix in sparse format with
 9 rows (elements/itemsets/transactions) and
 12 columns (items) and a density of 0.1296296 

most frequent items:
 542931 1014660 1088953 1123614 1138035 (Other) 
      3       1       1       1       1       7
```

Create frequent itemsets using `apriori()`:

```
freq_is <- apriori(tr, 
                   parameter = list(target = "frequent itemsets",
                                    support = 0.00001))
```

If you then inspect `freq_is`, you can see that the count is 3 for the itemset `{542931}`:

```
inspect(freq_is)
     items                               support   count
[1]  {542380}                            0.1111111 1    
[2]  {1123614}                           0.1111111 1    
[3]  {1014660}                           0.1111111 1    
[4]  {1088953}                           0.1111111 1    
[5]  {1138035}                           0.1111111 1    
[6]  {542614}                            0.1111111 1    
[7]  {546845}                            0.1111111 1    
[8]  {81387}                             0.1111111 1    
[9]  {360015}                            0.1111111 1    
[10] {542448}                            0.1111111 1    
[11] {542613}                            0.1111111 1    
[12] {542931}                            0.3333333 3 
.
.
.
[39] {81387,360015,542448,542613,542931} 0.1111111 1
```